# how to get the cached data in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I want to use the cache in spring boot that is loaded from the beginning, what I cannot understand is how I can call the data that is already cached from another class, in this case the list that I am caching. Thanks

```
     @Component
     public class ApplicationRunnerCache implements CommandLineRunner{

     @Autowired
     ItemType itemType;

     @Autowired
     private CacheManager cacheManager;

     @Bean
     public CacheManager cacheManager() {
     return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("types");
     }

     @Override
     public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
     List<ColtemType> result = itemType.findAll();
     result.forEach(type ->
            cacheManager.getCache("types").put(type.getItemTypeId(), type));
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

To use your cache you would `@Autowire` your `cacheManager` into *another* component and reference it from there. Try removing the autowired cacheManager from your code, you may not need it (not 100% sure about this).

e.g.

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
  private final CacheManager cacheManager;

  public MyComponent(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
  }

  public void doStuff(String typeId) {
    ColtemType type = cacheManager.getCache("types").get(typeId, ColtemType.class);
    // do stuff with type.
  }
}
```

NB: The thing that caught me out the first time I used spring caching, was that I used the cache annotations and they're nice, but they only work when you you call the methods from another class (due to the way interception works). So I switched to doing it using beans and autowiring and never looked back.

An optimisation you might consider... create a bean for your 'types' cache if you're looking it up frequently. There's probably little performance improvement, but the code might read nicer.

Answer (score 1):

If `run` method is the only client for the cache, then there is no point in even creating `CacheManager` or use any cache framework for that matter.

But Im assuming that is not the case. Ideally, you'd want to initialize cache and use it where ever required. This is how you create the cache:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig
{
    @Autowired
    ItemType itemType;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager()
    {
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Collections.singletonList(createCache()));
        return cacheManager;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Cache createCache()
    {
        Cache cache = new ConcurrentMapCache("default");
        
        // use `itemType` to populate cache.
        
        return cache;
    }
}
```

PS: It is important for a class annotated with `@EnableCaching` to have a method that returns `CacheManager`. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html)

Then you can use cache with simple `@Autowired`

```
@Configuration
public class UseCache
{
    @Autowired
    CacheManager cacheManager;
    
    public void useCacheManager()
    {
        // use cacheManager here
    }
}
```